# blur() / focus() after select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

JQM 1.3.2 / ASP.NET MVC 4

When selecting a value the focus isn't set correctly to the input field, what am i missing?

The surrounding typical jqm-shadow isn't removed from the select, the input gets the shadow effect, but the cursor isn't set into the input field.

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#IndexScanPage').on('change', '#locationCode', function (e) {
    $('#locationCode').blur();
    $('#_inputEAN').focus();
});
```

**part of the html-code:**

```
<div id="IndexScanPage">
    <select name="locationCode" id="locationCode" data-native-menu="false" data-icon="home">
        <option value='' data-placeholder="true">Lagerauswahl</option>
        @{
            foreach ( var location in Model.Locations)
            {
                <option value='@location.LocationCode'>@location.LocationDescription</option> 
            }
        }
    </select>

    <div class="ui-grid-solo">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
            <input id="_inputEAN" name="barcode" data-clear-btn="true" autocomplete="off" autofocus required />
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="Weiter" data-role="button" data-iconpos="right" data-icon="search" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

extended the fiddle from @Omar: http://jsfiddle.net/tronc/qMjy9/1/

clicking the extra button focuses the input correctly, why does the script code do not work?

Comment: `$(document).on('change', '#IndexScanPage, #locationCode', function (e) {` you're missing a comma in the selector above.

Comment: corrected it to: $('#IndexScanPage').on('change', '#locationCode', function (e){...} ; still doesn't work. Something is wrong with the focus() method

Comment: `#IndexScanPage` isn't parent of `#locationCode`, is it? this is not correct `$('#IndexScanPage').on('change', '#locationCode', function (e){...}`.

Comment: sorry, of course locationCode is a child of IndexScanPage, sorry for the confusing code example, had to copy it from some partials together. still focus() doesn't work cerrectly

Comment: try this code and on which browser are you testing your code? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/V2nma/

Comment: this doesn't work, too :(
tried in firefox,chrome and IE. does this work for you?!

Comment: looks like this: http://tinypic.com/r/25p6zb8/5
cursor isnt set into the input field and the shadows aren't removed until a real click into the input field...

Comment: You want to remove shadow from selectmenu? Use `$(' select a').removeClass('ui-shadow');`

Comment: please try my jsfiddle, shouldn't do `.focus()` the same job from script as from clicking the button?

Comment: it looks like you'll need to wait for jQM to update `select` styles and then `.focus()` input. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/qMjy9/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using selectmenu with `data-native-menu="false"` converts it into a popup and hides native selectmenu.

When you choose an option, it goes through several stages.

- Popup is closed / hidden
- Native selectmenu is updated
- jQM virtual selectmenu text is updated
- jQM virtual selectmenu gets focused

Thus, you need to wait until all the above steps are fulfilled.

```
$("#IndexScanPage").on('change', '#locationCode', function (e) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('#_inputEAN').focus();
  }, 50); // minimum value - tested on Chrome
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/UAW5k/)**

Comment: wow that did it, thank you so much! this was annoying as hell for more than 2 weeks. Where did you get this knowledge from, I want to learn more about this depths of jqm.

Comment: @tronc you're welcome :) It's about trial and error, nothing more. good luck :)

Comment: too bad, most of the time developing jqm you have to struggle with such things ;), but thanks anyway

Comment: @tronc true, jQM is full of surprises, mastering it requires time and practice.